# how would I perform two events when a dialog is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to perform two action when the jQuery dialog close button is clicked. I have two divs. I would like div to slide up and div 2 to slide down when I close the dialog.

so far I have managed to make div 1 slide up. So where can I place the code for div 2 in order to slide down after div1 slides up?

here is the code

```
$('#unlock').click(function(){

    $('#dialog_content').dialog({

        modal: true , resizable: false,

        close: function(event, ui) { $('#div1').slideUp();}

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just chain the slide calls

```
close: function(event, ui) {
  $('#div1').slideUp(function() {
    $('#div2').slideDown();
  });
};
```

Comment: @Hari whoops, updated and will be grabbing another cup of coffee

Comment: @FlorianMargaine the documentation suggests that it's necessary. Must be an issue with the docs http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: The documentation shows the parameter between square brackets, which means it's optional :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#unlock').click(function(){

$('#dialog_content').dialog({

    modal: true , resizable: false,

    close: function(event, ui) {
$('#div1').slideUp( function(){$('#div2').slideDown();});

}

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (function(){

      $("#unlock").on( "click", function() {
        $("#divone").slideUp();

      $("#divone").promise().done(function() {
         $( "#divtwo" ).slideDown();
      });

  });

})();
```

You could also use .promise(); to make sure all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished. might be a little overkill, but just another option